# Trigger one pipeline job multiple times using different parameters from Another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have a main job (A) which has multiple **trigger/call builds on other projects** step, and each has some different set of parameters values. All these steps were made to call the same pipeline job (B) with different parameters.

**Issue 1:** When we build the A job it triggers multiple B jobs and marks the execution as Success. But we want the A job status to wait until all the job it has triggered has ran completely (Pass or Fail doesn't matter). **Is this possible to do?** We want all the triggered pipeline jobs to run in parallel so using **Block until the triggered projects finish their build** check box is out of option.

**Issue 2:** If the A job has triggered 15 pipeline jobs and I have only 5 nodes available I want to run certain jobs first with high priority. Is that possible? We are using pipeline scripts is it possible to **set priority value for a job inside pipeline script**?

Comment: You can set `wait: true` when triggering the job so that it waits until the triggered job finishes.

Comment: Job A is a freestyle job and Job B is pipeline job . I won't be able to script anything there in Job A.